# flutter implemention of SlideTransition inside go_router StatefulShellRoute

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I'm tryign to make SlideTransition work with StatefulShellRoute.

I worked by the flutter team example [here](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/example/lib/others/custom_stateful_shell_route.dart), and it worked, but the SlideTransition needs a AnimationController and SingleTickerProviderStateMixin.

i tried to create statefull widget with the SlideTransition

```
class AnimatedBranchContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  /// Creates a AnimatedBranchContainer
  const AnimatedBranchContainer(
      {super.key, required this.currentIndex, required this.children});

  /// The index (in [children]) of the branch Navigator to display.
  final int currentIndex;

  /// The children (branch Navigators) to display in this container.
  final List<Widget> children;

  @override
  State<AnimatedBranchContainer> createState() =>
      _AnimatedBranchContainerState();
}

class _AnimatedBranchContainerState extends State<AnimatedBranchContainer>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    vsync: this,
  );
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
        children: widget.children.mapIndexed(
      (int index, Widget navigator) {
        return SlideTransition(
          position: Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(-1, 0), end: Offset.zero)
              .animate(CurvedAnimation(
                  parent: _controller, curve: Curves.elasticIn)),
          child: _branchNavigatorWrapper(index, navigator),
        );
      },
    ).toList());
  }

  Widget _branchNavigatorWrapper(int index, Widget navigator) => IgnorePointer(
        ignoring: index != widget.currentIndex,
        child: TickerMode(
          enabled: index == widget.currentIndex,
          child: navigator,
        ),
      );
}
```

but it didn't work, it shows a blank page, any advice ?

Comment: you don't use to your controller in any way (no `forward` / `reverse` method called), that's why no transition occurs

Comment: @pskink you're right, i forgot to call foward, after calling forward on build (i'm not sure its a good idea but i have no lifecycle hook invoked when the current index is updated) i reset the animation and forward it again, now i have a new problem, for some reason it keeps animating in the second branch even if navigate to the first route, i think it broke the StatefulShellRoute, is there any other way to do what i'm trying to do ?